# how to show Laravel welcome page when logged and non logged

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have Laravel Login system using Auth. need show to the user diffrent content at @sections as following when users are logged and non logged.
welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title' )
@guest
@section('content1')
<p>this is non logging content</p>
@include('partials._footer')
@endsection

@else

@section('content2')
<p>This is logging user content</p>
@endsection
@endguest
```

but in my logged user content is displaying in the non logged are also, how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @auth and @guest blade functions for that

```
@auth
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```